# Limpar valor do input no angular material

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

Tenho um `input` no Angular Material:

```
<mat-form-field 
    class="width-layout p-0 col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"
    [class.mat-form-field-invalid]="errorValue" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label [class.input_disabled]="isDisabled">Numero</mat-label>
    <input type="text" [readonly]="read" 
        matInput 
        formControlName="numero" 
        name="numero" 
        id="numero" 
        placeholder="numero" 
        (change)="valida($event.target.value)" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Onde ele só fica habilitado quando clica em um `checkbox`, caso o `checkbox` esteja ativado, ele pode alterar o valor inicial, se caso esteja desativado, o `input` fica desabilitado com o valor inicial.

Quando clico pra habilitador o input, coloco valor lá, e depois desabilito, volta pro valor normal, mas quando eu habilito de novo, o input volta pro valor anterior que eu coloquei, e nao zera.

Tentei deixar o `input` vazio assim:

```
if (checked === true) {
  this.couponForm.controls.numero.enable();
  (document.getElementById('numero') as HTMLInputElement).value = '';
}
```

Ele ate fica sem valor, mas quando passo o mouse no `input` ele já mostra o valor anterior, e não o `input` com o valor vazio como deveria ser.

Comment: Pq não faz um **property binding** no input pra poder controlar melhor isto?

Comment: @LeAndrade poderia me dar um exemplo de como usar no meu problema?

Comment: Precisaria ver como está o TS, só com estes código não tem como ter uma ideia.

Comment: @LeAndrade entendi, mas acabei de usar e nao funcionou. Depois que coloco um valor e desabilito e habilito de novo, vai o valor que digitei no input, e nao o que alterei no ts

Comment: Precisaria ver como estão os código como disse, pq se fez o property binding no input, na função de click do checkbox bastaria apenas zerar os valores da propriedade que fez binding.

Answer (score 3):

Olá.

## Pelo que eu vi você esta trabalhando com ReactForms, isso é bom. Então vamos a resposta:

1º Mudei a responsabilidade do "change" Para o CheckBox:

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="checkbox"  [checked]="true" (change)="change($event.checked)" >Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

2º Alterei a função e agora caso toda vez que o CheckBox estiver *true* o input é habilitado, se *false* o input volta para o valor *" "*  e desabilita o input do formulario.

```
change(checked: any){
    if(checked){
      this.form.controls['numero'].enable();
    } else if(!checked){
    this.form.controls['numero'].setValue('');
    this.form.controls['numero'].disable();
    }
  }
```

Caso Tenha alguma duvida é só falar.